# efficiently compute ordering permutations in numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, performance, numpy

I've got a numpy array. What is the fastest way to compute all the permutations of orderings.

What I mean is, given the first element in my array, I want a list of all the elements that sequentially follow it. Then given the second element, a list of all the elements that follow it.

So given my list: b, c, & d follow a. c & d follow b, and d follows c.

```
x = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d"])
```

So a potential output looks like:

```
[
    ["a","b"],
    ["a","c"],
    ["a","d"],

    ["b","c"],
    ["b","d"],

    ["c","d"],
]
```

I will need to do this several million times so I am looking for an efficient solution.

I tried something like:

```
im = np.vstack([x]*len(x))
a = np.vstack(([im], [im.T])).T
results = a[np.triu_indices(len(x),1)]
```

but its actually slower than looping...

Comment: Your method could be rewritten as `np.take(x, np.triu_indices(len(x), 1)).T`. This is faster, but the method suggested by Ashwini Choudhary still edges it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `itertools`'s functions like [`chain.from_iterable`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain.from_iterable) and [`combinations`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations) with [`np.fromiter`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.fromiter.html) for this. This involves no loop in Python, but still not a pure NumPy solution:

```
>>> from itertools import combinations, chain
>>> arr = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(combinations(x, 2)), dtype=x.dtype)
>>> arr.reshape(arr.size/2, 2)
array([['a', 'b'],
       ['a', 'c'],
       ['a', 'd'],
       ..., 
       ['b', 'c'],
       ['b', 'd'],
       ['c', 'd']], 
      dtype='|S1')
```

**Timing comparisons:**

```
>>> x = np.array(["a", "b", "c", "d"]*100)
>>> %%timeit
    im = np.vstack([x]*len(x))
    a = np.vstack(([im], [im.T])).T
    results = a[np.triu_indices(len(x),1)]
... 
10 loops, best of 3: 29.2 ms per loop
>>> %%timeit
    arr = np.fromiter(chain.from_iterable(combinations(x, 2)), dtype=x.dtype)
    arr.reshape(arr.size/2, 2)
... 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.63 ms per loop
```

Comment: I get completely different timings to you (3ms vs 9ms). Are you sure your timings are correct (eg. did you paste the right setup)? I'm on Numpy 1.9.1.

Comment: @Veedrac Yes. Mine is 1.8.2.

Comment: I tested it on [here](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/try-ipython/) as well and got 44 ms vs 10 ms. They are using 1.8.1.

Answer (score 3):

I've been browsing the source and it seems the `tri` functions have had some very substantial improvements relatively recently. [The file is all Python](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/master/numpy/lib/twodim_base.py) so you can just copy it into your directory if that helps.

I seem to have completely different timings to Ashwini Chaudhary, even after taking this into account.

It is very important to know the size of the arrays you want to do this on; if it is small you should cache intermediates like `triu_indices`.

The fastest code for me was:

```
def triangalize_1(x):
    xs, ys = numpy.triu_indices(len(x), 1)
    return numpy.array([x[xs], x[ys]]).T
```

unless the `x` array is small.

If `x` is small, caching was best:

```
triu_cache = {}
def triangalize_1(x):
    if len(x) in triu_cache:
        xs, ys = triu_cache[len(x)]

    else:
        xs, ys = numpy.triu_indices(len(x), 1)
        triu_cache[len(x)] = xs, ys

    return numpy.array([x[xs], x[ys]]).T
```

I wouldn't do this for large `x` because of memory requirements.